# Ubuntu 12.04 sometimes doesn't halt completely

Tags: nvidia, 12.04, shutdown

I am using an Dell Latitude D830 with Ubuntu 12.04.
Now, when I turn off the pc, Ubuntu doesn't halt completely sometimes.
I think that is due to the latest Nvidia drivers, because in the past with Ubuntu 10.10 I installed the latest drivers released by nvidia and I had the same problem.
By now, "messages" file / var / log is always empty.
My video card is: NVIDIA Corporation G86M [Quadro NVS 135M]
PC will not turn off even with "halt -p".

Comment: do you see any ACPI errors in ``/var/log/dmesg`` ?

Comment: This is the only strange message: [2.591986] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work. (but it's at boot and the current driver work)

Comment: ...Same with me: Dell 830, shutdown hangs. I found ist was dropbox that prevented shutdown. When i stop dropbox before shutdown it's ok. For the clean Solution? no idea! greetings guges

Comment: I actually removed dropbox and will now shut down properly.I also tried installing the latest available version, but without success. With which command you stop dropbox?

Comment: Unfortunately is not dropbox causing the problem. Although I do not have Dropbox, sometimes, the problem is the same.

Comment: [Resolved] I removed the nvidia proprietary driver and I installed the nouveau driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be related to this bug seen on Dell m1330, though only seen if using a 32 bit install & nvidia drivers 295.XX - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/940564

Similar question here - [Shutdown issues on my Dell XPS M1530](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126729/shutdown-issues-on-my-dell-xps-m1530)

Possible solution other than going back to nouveau or downgrading to nvidia driver 290.20 - [Dell Studio 1569 Cannot Shutdown in Ubuntu 11.10 or 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122933/dell-studio-1569-cannot-shutdown-in-ubuntu-11-10-or-12-04)

Answer (score 3):

I think I solved it by edditing the reboot options in the grub file. How? just edit /etc/default/grub and search for the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" and add the ACPI option force, to become 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
This did the work for me. Hope it helps you guys too.

Comment: this worked on my pc.