# Shutdown issues on my Dell XPS M1530

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

On my Dell XPS M1530 lapttop, I am facing issues with shut-down option after upgrading to 12.04 LTS from 11.10. Sometimes it shutdowns "cleanly". But other times everything goes down but I can still see the power LED glowing (even after removing the power cord). If I keep it like that laptop temperature increases. So finally I opt for "hard shut-down" (i.e. pressing the power button on).

Any thoughts what is happening here?.

Edit:

I just found this link to already reported bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/987933

Comment: you may wish to glance at this bug, may be related to your circumstance, may not at all. In this case i've found only the 290.XX drivers work well on 32 bit install, 64 bit is not affected.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/940564

Comment: This may fix for some http://askubuntu.com/questions/122933/dell-studio-1569-cannot-shutdown-in-ubuntu-11-10-or-12-04

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work :(

Comment: I think you have answered your question.  You answer your known question and close this.

Comment: Also see  http://askubuntu.com/questions/126729/shutdown-issues-on-my-dell-xps-m1530

Answer (score 0):

I have a Thinkpad t42. Upgraded to 12.04. Clean install. On shutdown it returns to password screen.  Only way to shutdown was to hold power button.  When you log back in again,  go to restart. When the system is up then shutdown in the normal way and it works ok

Comment: I already tried that but not working in my case.