# Ubuntu 14.04 not shutting down completely

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I recently switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I press shutdown, the screen with the Ubuntu logo and dots comes up, and the orange dots start moving, but then stops as soon as it reaches the last two dots. I tried using the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122933/dell-studio-1569-cannot-shutdown-in-ubuntu-11-10-or-12-04), but it didn't work. Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the terminal command:

```
$ sudo init 0
```

or `$ shutdown`.

Init 0 should shut down.

If it no workee, try using saucy, precise, or upgrading your distro with `$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade.`

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these worked, though now it reaches the filled dots stage... any other ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Try disabling plymouth:

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing Ctrl+alt+F1 and enter to a tty window. Then do a

`sudo shutdown now`

or

`sudo init 0`

see what happens.

Comment: These commands should work if entered into a terminal window as well (which can be summoned using Ctrl+Alt+T).

Comment: Yes, this initializes the shutdown sequence, but it still only reaches the shutdown screen before stalling... any other ideas?
Thanks!