# Ubuntu 14.04 not shutting down properly

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, thinkpad

When I try to shut down my newly installed Ubuntu 14.04 on 
my Thinkpad T440p, it get stuck at the screen with the 
ubuntu logo and lighted dots.  I saw there were other 
people that experienced this problem, but did not see 
answer that worked.  I have tried many of the suggested 
possible answers with no success.  Shutdown -h now does 
not work either.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Other suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Quick search : http://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer and http://askubuntu.com/questions/122933/dell-studio-1569-cannot-shutdown-in-ubuntu-11-10-or-12-04 This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why `sudo shutdown -h now` wouldn't work? Probably not the answer you are looking for, but might give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with fujitsu simens.
I used the kernel 3.11.10-03111015-generic and the problem is solved.